# What is the preferred way to load resource intensive dependencies into a Gunicorn worker process?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gunicorn

I need to load some large ML models into a [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) worker process. Assuming that I cannot preload the application pre-fork via Gunicorn (some dependencies aren't threadsafe) or move to a more sophisticated memory/resource/tensor sharing strategy using ZMQ or similar in the near future, where is the most appropriate place in the Gunicorn worker lifecycle to do this *before* the worker timeout begins running? I have tried using a custom Gunicorn worker class and a custom Gunicorn application and the relevant methods(`worker::load_wsgi`, `application::load`, etc.) but either the context doesn't apply to the worker or the worker's timeout has already begun counting down.

UPDATE: I've also tried using the hook API and these all seem to trigger the CUDA thread safety issue referenced implicitly above.

The quick and dirty solution, of course, is to increment the worker timeout but I don't want to do this for fear of negatively affecting performance of the application (e.g., long running zombie processes if the client disconnects).

Comment: Would [quantizing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html) the models to make them somewhat smaller help?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge, @ndrwnaguib. Unfortunately, my application is just a consumer of pre-existing models.

Comment: In the past, I've done this via [tensorflow serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving), with the gunicorn workers talking to the tensorflow serving service over HTTP. This saves memory because multiple gunicorn processes can share a model without having multiple copies in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks, @NickODell. I think this or Pytorch Serve is indeed the long term solution but it's too radical a change for my current use case.